# Openlayers 3 heatmap with weight function

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-2, heat-map

I have created an OpenLayers 3 heatmap. Because my weight column is not in the range 0-1, I need to use a function to divide it by the maximum value (which I know). I am doing the following:

```
var lyr_airports = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
    source:jsonSource_airports, 
    radius: 20,
    weight: function(){'ELEV'/1569},
    title: "airports"
});
```

Is that correct? In other words, does it recognize column names like that in the function, or do I need to reference the column fully? If the latter (in this example), how?

**Edit**
Just spotted a horribly basic error: no `return`. Will fix that and retest.

Comment: Is it `weight: function(feature){return feature.properties['ELEV'];}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The weight function takes a feature as an attribute (Code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/layer/heatmap.js)). You can use it like that:

```
var lyr_airports = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
    // ...
    weight: function(feature){
        // get your feature property
        var weightProperty = feature.get('ELEV');
        // perform some calculation to get weightProperty between 0 - 1
        weightProperty = weightProperty /1569; // this was your suggestion - make sure this makes sense
        return weightProperty;
    }
});
```